# I get NoReverseMatch at /signup/ after filling my signup form

Tags: django, django-views

I've tried using redirect, reverse, reverse_lazy, all gives the same error: **NoReverseMatch at /signup/**. However, HttpResponseRedirect appends the redirect page to the signup url. That is  for example I get localhost:8000/signup/home instead of localhost:8000/home

Below is my view, error stack trace and urls files.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class SignUp(FormView):
    template_name = 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html'
    form_class = ClientForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ClientForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html', context)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        Client.objects.create(name=name, schema_name=name, domain_url=name + ".localhost")
        return redirect('')
```

URL.py file:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import SignUp, signup

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUp.as_view(), name="sign_up"),
    path('home/', include('blogApi.urls'), name=''),
    
]
```

Below is the error stack tree

```
Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/customer/views.py", line 28, in form_valid
    return redirect('')
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 41, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 131, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/marvelous/PycharmProjects/blogApiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: try `path('signup', [...]` and what is imported by `from .views import signup`?

Comment: sorry, that isn't clear.

Comment: can you please post the complete error traceback, I guess your URL mapping is buggy.

Comment: I just did that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems your `SignUp` view fails to return a proper redirect.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class SignUp(FormView):
    template_name = 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html'
    form_class = ClientForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ClientForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html', context)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        Client.objects.create(name=name, schema_name=name, domain_url=name + ".localhost")
        return redirect('/home/')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import SignUp, signup

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUp.as_view(), name="sign_up"),
    path('home/', include('blogApi.urls'), name='home'),
    
]
```

Please see the [official docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/) for the `redirect` method.

To redirect to another URL, you can either set a hardcoded URL or an absolute URL. From the docu:

```
# By passing a hardcoded URL to redirect to:

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')

# This also works with full URLs:

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

Don't overcimplicate things by defining strings with only `''` etc., at some point you either get stuck or can't guess your own logic anymore. Define reasonable names.

Comment: Thanks, This worked. But why can't I call it with url "name" variable, instead of hardcording?

Comment: because the `redirect` method doesn't accept the url's name as argument. Glad it helped!